# Does Scrapy work on .cfm files?

Tags: scrapy, cfml

So far my experience with Scrapy spiders are for a focused scrapying.  In another word, I first do a manual keyword search on a target website, which return a http address containing the keywords, an example is `http://www.simplyhired.com/search?q=Anesthesiologist`.  This weblink will let my spider "see" what I got in a browser.

Now I noticed this method doesn't work on some websites, such as this one: `http://www.physicianjobboard.com/`.  Keyword searching works on a browser, but only generates a generic weblink of `http://www.mdjobsite.com/Index2.cfm?Page=JobsSearchResults`.  This generic web link contains `.cfm` file and would not directly let my spiders know which keywords I am interested in.

One inefficient method would be scrapying all the posts from this website and filter out those I need.  Are there another method to let my spiders see what I got in my browser and perform a focused scrapying?  My guess is to let spider send a request mimicking keyword search and then analyze the response page. I have zero experience on this.  Could anyone give some hints if my guess is correct?

Comment: can't understand this, do you have some code examples or logs to see your real problem? if you are talking about xpath inside cfm file, it should work, I just checked the one you passed.

Comment: Use `http://www.physicianjobboard.com/` as the example, I can do a keyword search (such as `Anesthesiologist`) in a browser and the browser will a list of jobs related to anesthesiology.  At the same time, the http address for the aforementioned search result will be `http://www.mdjobsite.com/Index2.cfm?Page=JobsSearchResults`.   If I copy and paste this http address into a new browser window, I will NOT see the same search result, because the http address doesn't contain the keyword (`Anesthesiologist`) used.  So the question is: how to let spiders "see" the job list from the keyword search?

Comment: this is not related to scrapy, but to the website.

Comment: Exactly.  My question is: can scrapy deal with this type of website?  I believe so, but don't know how.